# Replace NA by "No_"colname"_found"

Tags: r, na

I want to replace every NA in my dataframe with "No_[colname]_found".
(If there is a value, I want to keep it.) I know I can do it for every column separately but I have > 100 columns.

First, I tried replacing every NA in my dataframe with the colname. I know how to add "No_" and "_found" (by using paste).
This is what I have tried so far without success:

```
DF <- apply(DF, 2, function(x){ifelse(is.na(x), colnames(DF)[x], x)})
DF <- apply(DF, 2, function(x){ifelse(is.na(x), colnames(x), x)})
DF <- apply(DF, 2, function(x){ifelse(is.na(x), colnames(DF[x]), x)})
```

With what I tried so far, I don't get error messages. But my NA values don't change into colname, they stay NAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `lapply` over the names of the input data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,NA,3), v2=c(4,5,6), v3=c(NA,8,NA))
output <- data.frame(lapply(names(df), function(x) {
    ifelse(is.na(df[[x]]), paste0("No_", x, "_found"), df[[x]])
}))
names(output) <- names(df)

df

  v1 v2 v3
1  1  4 NA
2 NA  5  8
3  3  6 NA

output

           v1 v2          v3
1           1  4 No_v3_found
2 No_v1_found  5           8
3           3  6 No_v3_found
```